# In chrome, is it possible to trigger a shortcut to pdf print window of current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, pdf, printing

Manually, I would do it by

1. ctrl+p
2. save as pdf
3. open that pdf
4. ctrl+p
5. select printer
6. click print button

Is it possible to create a script that would skip steps 1-5?

I've searched about this topic but I can't find a definitive solution. I've read about html-to-pdf generators, but if the above steps can be done via js or something, I'd prefer that.

Thanks a lot.